# how can I get one value among objects with duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I've got an array:

```
list=[{ id:1, title:aaa, day:"mon"}, { id:2, title:bbb, day:"mon"}]
```

I want to get only one word "mon" from that arrangement.
I tried like this

```
console.log(props.list.day);
```

but the result was undefined.
how can I get it with javascript?

Comment: `console.log(list[0][‘day’])`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you trying to access the `day` property in the first element of the list, or are you trying to retrieve the first element in the list whose day matches "mon" ?

Comment: Could you be more spefic? The question doesn't state what actually you are trying to sccomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let list=[{ id:1, title:'aaa', day:"mon"}, { id:2, title:'bbb', day:"mon"}]

console.log(list[0].day);
console.log(list[1].day);

// all day in an array

const arr = list.map(a=>a.day)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the first item's day:

```
console.log(this.props.list[0].day);
```

But take into consideration that, like I said, it'll access the first object in the array. If you want to take into consideration all other items, you might want to store them in another array. Something like this:

```
let list=[{ id:1, title:'aaa', day:'mon'}, { id:2, title:'bbb', day:'mon'}]

// store all 'days' inside an array
let days = []
list.forEach(ele => {
    days.push(ele.day)
})

console.log(days) // [ "mon", "mon" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `.map()` your array of objects to an array of days, and then put that array into a `Set` to remove duplicates. Lastly, you can then use `Array.from()` to retrieve unique values from your set as an array:

```js
const list = [{id:1, title:'aaa', day:"mon"}, {id:2, title:'bbb', day:"mon"}, {id:3, title:'ccc', day:"tue"}];

const unique_days = Array.from(new Set(list.map(({day}) => day)));
console.log(unique_days);
```